# Protocols with associated types compile error: Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols, associated-types

My goal is to create a modular network service layer which can easily be unit tested.

In the quest for that, I started simply with the following protocol:

```
protocol NetworkService {
    associatedtype Response
    func fetchData() async throws -> Response
}
```

I then proceed to create a service to fetch the news feed like so:

```
struct FetchNewsService: NetworkService {
    typealias Response = [NewsAssetModel]
    
    func fetchData() async throws -> Response {
        guard let fetchNewsURL = URL(string: SystemConstants.NetworkConstants.fetchNewsEndpoint) else {
            throw NetworkError.invalidURL
        }
        
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: fetchNewsURL)
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        
        guard let (data, response) = try? await session.data(for: urlRequest) else {
            // Would need to handle no internet error as well
            throw NetworkError.server
        }
        
        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
           httpResponse.statusCode > 400 {
            throw NetworkError.server
        }
        
        guard let newsResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(NewsResponseModel.self,
                                                           from: data) else {
            throw NetworkError.decode
        }
        
        return newsResponse.assets
    }
}
```

In my view model, I would like to make a request to fetch the news feed items and so I wanted to inject a type of `NetworkService` into my view model.

```
class NewsAssetManager {
    private(set) var newsAssets: [NewsAssetModel] = []
    private var newsService: NetworkService // 1 - error on this line
    
    // 2 - and this line below
    init(withNewsService newsService: NetworkService = FetchNewsService()) {
        
    }
}
```

The first error that I get at the property declaration is `Protocol 'NetworkService' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

The second error that I get at the initializer is also the same `Protocol 'NetworkService' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

What am I doing incorrectly and how can I fix / improve this ?

**Update with generics**

```
protocol NetworkService {
    func fetchData<T>() async throws -> T 
}
```

```
struct FetchNewsService: NetworkService {
    func fetchData<T>() async throws -> T {
        guard let fetchNewsURL = URL(string: SystemConstants.NetworkConstants.fetchNewsEndpoint) else {
            throw NetworkError.invalidURL
        }
        
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: fetchNewsURL)
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        
        guard let (data, response) = try? await session.data(for: urlRequest) else {
            // Would need to handle no internet error as well
            throw NetworkError.server
        }
        
        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
           httpResponse.statusCode > 400 {
            throw NetworkError.server
        }
        
        guard let newsResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(NewsResponseModel.self, from: data)
        else {
            throw NetworkError.decode
        }
        
        return newsResponse.assets // Compile error
    }
}
```

I get an error on the last line `Cannot convert return expression of type '[NewsAssetModel]' to return type 'T'`

**Update based on comments & Answer**

Adding a combination of Any & Some to the property or initialiser still doesn't get rid of the compilation errors faced.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I also confirmed via terminal and this code that I at least am running Swift 5.6:

```
#if swift(>=5.6)
        print("swift 5.6")
#endif
```

Comment: Do you really need an associated type, isn’t it enough if the function is generic? Otherwise use `any`.

Comment: without the associated type, I was getting errors which I could also attribute to not setting it up properly. What is the minimum Swift version required to use Any ? This doesn't seem to work when I use it with Swift 5.6.1

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - thanks for the info but I still don't grasp your solution fully. I have added a small update towards the end of my question - is this what you mean by replacing typealias and using generics instead ? I do like your suggestion of using Response instead of [Response], however, I still don't grasp how I can replace the typealias and get this to work with just generics.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - my aim was to create a generic protocol and specialise it during the implementation. So my struct `FetchNewsService` will only be responsible for fetching the news service. and I might create another service for something else which conforms to `NetworkService`. Then in my view models, I would be able to inject any `NetworkService` type. Maybe this is not possible or there is a flaw in my design / thinking ?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - just tried that and updated my question. The combination of some and any still leaves me facing compilation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would define the protocol when not using an associated type. Make the function generic instead and the type should conform to `Decodable`

```
protocol NetworkService {
    func fetchData<Response: Decodable>(url: URL) async throws -> Response
}
```

Then I would change the implementation of the conforming type to

```
struct FetchNewsService: NetworkService {
    func fetchData<Response: Decodable>(url: URL) async throws -> Response {
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

        guard let (data, response) = try? await session.data(for: urlRequest) else {
            throw NetworkError.server
        }

        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
           httpResponse.statusCode > 400 {
            throw NetworkError.server
        }

        do {
            return try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
        } catch {
            throw NetworkError.decode(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Now the implementation isn't so hardcoded to one solution, actually it is so general that we can move it into an extension of the protocol

```
extension NetworkService {
    func fetchData<Response: Decodable>(url: URL) async throws -> Response {
        // same code as above
    }
}
```

Which means in this case `FetchNewsService` isn't needed anymore and it can be deleted.

The `NewsAssetManager` can then be changed to below where all the code that is specific to this particular api and response type now resides.

```
class NewsAssetManager {
    private(set) var newsAssets: [NewsAssetModel] = []
    private var newsService: NetworkService

    init(withNewsService newsService: NetworkService) {
        self.newsService = newsService
    }

    func fetchNews() async throws {
        guard let fetchNewsURL = URL(string: SystemConstants.NetworkConstants.fetchNewsEndpoint) else {
            throw NetworkError.invalidURL
        }
        let model: NewsResponseModel = try await newsService.fetchData(url: fetchNewsURL)
        newsAssets = model.assets
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Joakim. This is fixed all my errors and also helped me achieve the goal I set out to achieve. Extremely grateful for the time you spent helping me.

Answer (score 0):

When I put your code in Xcode, the compiler tells me how to fix it:

Change

```
private var newsService: NetworkService
```

to

```
private var newsService: any NetworkService
```

and change

```
init(withNewsService newsService: NetworkService = FetchNewsService())
```

to

```
init(withNewsService newsService: any NetworkService = FetchNewsService())
```

The only difference is the keyword `any`.

Comment: What is the minimum Swift version required to use Any ? This doesn't seem to work when I use it with Swift 5.6.1

Comment: 5.6. See this article from Hacking with Swift:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/247/whats-new-in-swift-5-6

Comment: Have a look at my updated question towards the end, section `Update based on comments & Answer` - I did what you suggested and still see the compilation error.